# How to fix white background of all webpages in all browsers?

Tags: windows-7, windows, display, accessibility

For more that 2 years I am facing a screen resolution problem in my laptop computer which uses Win7 x86 (Ultimate). To describe you what exactly happens I will give you some examples. When the pc starts I don't see the blue font of windows but a white screen with only Welcome message. In Firefox I don't see background images anymore. Everything is white. Here it's a screenshot.

[image: Screnshot]

It's a huge problem because I can't even see the buttons in websites.

Everything started after I installed a program in my laptop with some tests in flash mode I think (but I am not sure) and program asked me to change resolution from 1280 x 800 to 1280x720 or 1204x768 or 800x600 (sorry but I don't remember it). After I change it I kept it for some weeks and when I turned it back to 1280 x 800 (original) then I had these problems. That what I think is that the pc made automatic changes and then it didn't change them.

Thanks for your time. I hope someone could help me.

Comment: Do you remember the name of that program?

Comment: no sorry, it was a program with questions. like a test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have accidentally [high contrast mode](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows-vista/Turn-on-High-Contrast-and-change-the-settings).

To turn it off, press <kbd>LAlt</kbd><kbd>LShift</kbd><kbd>PrintScreen</kbd>.

If it does not work, start the accessibility manager by pressing <kbd>Start</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> and turn it off from there.

Comment: I pressed the keys but it didn't work. I also wend at "Make the computer easier to see" but Everything was off except first three tickboxes(Alt Shift PrintScreen and the two bellow). Should I make any restart or something else? Thanks for your time.

Comment: update. I made restart but still the same proble.

Comment: In “Make the computer easier to see” you should click the first link and choose a non-HC composition.

Comment: Yes it worked!! Thank you. I changed theme and it fixed! Now I see backgrounds and all images!! thanks again.

Answer (score -2):

try to update your hardware drivers

this applications can help you with that.

-driverpack solution

-iobit driver booster

i cannot give the link because the website thinks it is a spam so just try to search it in google.

if it did not fix it, try to install new fresh OS on your laptop